# OpenGL Texturing mapping and coordinates strange Issue

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

This is how it looks right now (only half scene has been drawn to let you see the bottom texture).I have upload some screens because they're better than 1000 words.

[image: d]

Zoom (buildings seems to have totally random coords)
[image: df]
How it should look 
[image]

Another example
[image]

Here I load textures:

```
glGenTextures(sceneList.count(), &mTextureID[0]);

for (QList<SceneObject*>::ConstIterator i = sceneList.begin();i!=sceneList.end();++i) {
    Mesh* p = dynamic_cast<Mesh*>(*i);
    if(p){
        if (p->HasTexture()){
            QImage* a =  p->Mat().GetTexture()->GetImage();
            *a= QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(*a);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID[counter]);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, p->Mat().GetTexture()->ImageSize().width() , p->Mat().GetTexture()->ImageSize().height() , 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, a.bits());
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
}
```

Then for every mesh i do this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID[counter]);     //where counter=texture for current mesh
...
const QList<Vector3D> vertices=p.Vertices();
QList<Face>& faccie=p.Faces();
int numerofacce=faccie.count();
QList<Vector3D>& normals =p.Normals();
int numerovertici=0
for (int t = 0; t < numerofacce; ++t) {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ...
    switch(f.numVertici) {
    case 1:
        a[1]++;
        face_mode = GL_POINTS;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if(hasNormals)
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
        numerovertici++;
        break;
    case 2:

        face_mode = GL_LINES;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if(hasNormals){
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[1]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
        }
        else{
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
        }
        numerovertici+=2;
        break;
    case 3:

        face_mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
        glBegin(face_mode);
        if (numerovertici<p.Vertices().count()-3){
        if(hasNormals){
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).y);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[0]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).y);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[1]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+2).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+2).y);
            glNormal3fv(&normals[(f.normalIndex)[2]].pos[0]);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[2]].pos[0]);
        }
        else{
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[0]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+1).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[1]].pos[0]);
            glTexCoord2f(p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+2).x, p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+2).y);
            glVertex3fv(&vertices[lista[2]].pos[0]);
        }
        numerovertici+=3;
        break;
    default: face_mode = GL_POLYGON; break;
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ...
```

**PRE:** Vertices number=number of texture coordinatess

Every glTexCoord2f contains something like p.TextureCoords().at(numerovertici+2).x where

```
*p* is the current mesh
*TextureCoords()* is a QList<Vector3D> that contains all the 2D coords
*at(numerovertici)* : takes from TextureCoords List the "numerovertici" element
*.x* taking x coordinate
```

So,I am using a vertices counter named "numerovertici" to remember how many vertices were drawn,and before drawing each vertex I am calling the correspondent texture coordinate.

Is this a coordinates problem (I'm pretty sure they're ok) or should it be something else?

PS:I've tried using glTexCoord2f right before glvertex but there is no difference.

Comment: Ick, don't put `glVertex3f (...)` on the same line as `glTexCoord2f (...)`. I had to re-format your code before I even found any calls to `glVertex3f (...)` :-\ My guess would be it has something to do with your use of `p.TextureCoords ().at (...)`, while all of the other vertex attributes have simple arrays that store their contents. I'd need to see your implementation of this `TextureCoords (...)` method.

Comment: Notwithstanding that all of this glVertex3f stuff is deprecated and you really should be using vertex and index buffers.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman code and description updated,hoping its more clear now.

Comment: Solved days ago,the coordinates were taken in a wrong order.